# how to copy files from local to remote by using ant ... in detail

Tags: ant, scp

what we need to know for copying the file other than ant Please explain in brief do we need to install anything like openssh or not needed or any other way without installing.

Comment: The title of the question asks how to copy files "by using ant", yet the body of the question asks "other than ant." These statements contradict each other. Which is correct? Further, what OS is running on the remote host? Is SSH or FTP or something else running on the remote host?

Answer (score 1):

The [SCP](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) task allows you to copy files to remote hosts. It does not require openSSH on the machine running Ant (it uses [jsch.jar](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/index.html) as specified in [ant library dependencies](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies))- obviously, it (or another SSH Server) will be required on the target!

Comment: Installed openSSH in the remote box but not able to start the service showing ERROR 1067.